# Building PyCrypto with fastmath (gmp or mpir) via pip on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, pycrypto

I installed PyCrypto on Windows via pip but i was not able to build Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath because GMP was not found.

I know there is a binary version on [voidspace](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto) but i would like to build the latest version of PyCrypto

Comment: Which Windows version? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: A simpler solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432010/exception-while-installing-packages-in-python/30620019#30620019

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following one is a way to achieve your goal. There are other, probably better ways (e.g. based on Visual Studio), but this one has worked for me. Additionally, it does not use `pip`.

All operations are carried out on a command prompt.

1. Install [Mingw](http://www.mingw.org/), including MSYS and the Development Toolkit. This will give you a fairly complete Unix-like development environment.
2. Ensure that Mingw binaries are in PATH environment variable. You need `MinGW\bin` and `MingGW\msys\1.0\bin`.
3. Download [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/) sources in a temporary directory. It is important you do **not** use 2.5.1 because of a bug that will break the build. 2.5.0 is fine.
4. Build the MPIR library. This is fairly straightforward: execute `bash configure` followed by `make`.
5. **HACK #1** Copy `libmpir.a` from `mpir-2.5.0\.libs` into `C:\Python2.7.1\libs`. This is necessary because `distutils` is broken and I could not find a way to direct it to the correct library location.
6. **HACK #2** Edit `C:\Python2.7.1\Lib\distutils\cygwincompiler.py` and remove any occurrance of the string `-mno-cygwin`. The reason is explained [here](http://www.secker.nl/2012/03/08/setup-python-2-7-2-and-mingw-on-windows-xp/).
7. Download [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) sources and unpack them in another temporary directory.
8. Set `CPPFLAGS` environment variable to the MPIR directory, which contains `mpir.h`.
9. **HACK 3** Edit `setup.py` and add the following line in `build_extension` method:

   > self.__add_compiler_option(os.environ['CPPFLAGS'])
10. Run `bash configure`. You should see two lines saying:

    > checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp... no
    >   checking for __gmpz_init in -lmpir... yes
11. Execute `python setup.py build -c mingw32`. You should see no errors.
12. Execute `python setup.py test` to verify that everything is fine.
13. Execute `python setup.py install` to copy the files into your local Python repository.
14. Alternatively, run `python setup.py bdist_wininst` to create an installer.

I really hate all the various hacks, and I'd love to hear if they can be avoided.

Comment: You don't have to do steps **5** and **9** if in step **8** you set `CPATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables to values `CPATH=C:\<path_to_mpir.h>` and `LIBRARY_PATH=C:\<path_to_libmpir.a>`